# How to align the UITableViewCell imageview to the edge of the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello I am using native `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView`. When I set the image of the cell it looks like image view not aligned to the 0th `x` position in `UITableViewCell`. There is a gap or padding between the `UITableView` & the `cell.imageView`. I did like this in `cellForRowAtIndex`

```
CGRect imgRect=cell.imageView.frame;
imgRect.origin.x=0;
cell.imageView.frame=imgRect;
```

but still same. nothing changed. How can I align the cell image to the edge of the table. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You can't change the position as well as the size of the cell imageview, it can be resizable with cell size. For that you have to use your custom cell..

Comment: You have to create a custom cell for that and in this you can take an imageview in your customccell in your tableview. Simply adjust the position of imageview according to your needs, need to do code for this thing. EVerything thing will manage from storyboard itself.

Comment: click ur tableview and from the "Show Attributes inspector you will see an option of "Dynamic prototypes". Below that we have the options of "Prototypes cell", increase value from "0" to "1" and your tableview will come with an "prototype cells" option. Now you can drag an imageview into the custom cell and align it's position. But in "cell for row at index path method " you have to chnage your code a little bit. I hope you will find this code anywhere on the internet or go for tutorial part if things are not clear

Answer (score -1):

To align the image view to the leading edge of the content view, first you need to create the custom UITableviewCell, follow below steps to create subclass(see the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html) to create custom tableviewcell)

Choose File > New > File (or press Command-N).

On the left of the dialog that appears, select Source under iOS.

Select Cocoa Touch Class, and click Next.

In the “Subclass of” field, select UITableViewCell and create tableview subclass named "CustomTableViewCell".

Open Storyboard, in the outline view, select Table View Cell.

Open the Identity inspector. find the field labeled Class and select "CustomTableViewCell" from the list.

after the tableviewcell is done drag the imageview and set the constraints for top, bottom and leading to the cell content view and keep the constant as 0. Add the height and width constraint for imageview.

[image]